# how to avoid old log messages when restarting the TailerListener

Tags: java, tail

I am using TailerListener API for monitoring log files. It's working fine if process started.
 If we restart the TailerListener,ii is monitoring  logs which are older than this process start up time. Is there any way to avoid this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I edited your question a tiny bit but geez, make an effort of at least posting something people can read.  Punctation and missing capitals are **not** hard to do correctly even if you're not a native english speaker.

Answer (score 0):

`File` in java has a `lastModified()` method. Before creating the `Tailer`, check it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. by Using lastModified() method we can check whether new log messages are added in log file.But how to monitor new log messages alone.

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to have to clarify your question, as I have no idea what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Is your file being rotated? See if below is what you are asking, because I have run into this before. When the file is rotated the default behavior seems to be to spit out all the log message from the whole log file, instead of only new log messages.
So my question would be, how do I override fileRotated() in TailerListener or change the behavior to avoid rolling the whole log file again (old and new messages)?